# File Upload Field not working

Tags: forms, 8

I just tried to create a simple **mandatory** file upload field in a custom form like this:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

  $form['pdf_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => $this->t('PDF File'),
    '#description' => $this->t('PDF files only'),
    //'#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

And that did not work.

When submitting a file (no matter what kind of), i get this error all the time:

"PDF File field is required."

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

I am using Drupal 8.2

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the required line. Updated code:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

  $form['pdf_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => $this->t('PDF File'),
    '#description' => $this->t('PDF files only'),
    //'#multiple' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

**Update**: As upload fields can not be required in PHP, just make it required in JS/jQuery

Add this code to a JS file:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if( $(".pdf-file-field").files.length == 0 ){
    alert("Please add a file");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Note: Instead of "event.preventDefault()", you [should](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) also be able to use return false.

Comment: Cannot. It is a mandatory field for the use case I am building.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I did not even know that the #required flag is not usable for file upload fields.

Comment: @Martin If my answer solved your problem, could you accept my (answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer]?

Comment: I solved it differently. I used the validate method inside the form class to ask if any file has been uploaded. Your solution is quite good for usuability.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'file_managed' instead of 'file':

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class ExampleFileManagedForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\Form
 */
class ExampleFileManagedForm extends FormBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'example_file_managed_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    $form['pdf'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Image'),
      '#upload_location' => 'public://pdf/',
      '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf'),
      ),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dump($form_state->getValue('pdf')); die();

  }

}
```

This will output an array holding the newly created file id:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "467"
]
```

and I have tested that the required feature works as expected.